# How can I use jar library in windows phone 7

Tags: android, windows-phone-7

I just start to develop for windows phone.
I wand to convert my apps from android to windows phone.
For one of the apps I need to use java library (jar).
My question is how can I use this jar in the windows phone app?
I try to convert this jar to dll but I can't add this dll because is not a windows phone dll.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only option is to make the application use a webservice, you then have to build the webservice using java.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't write Java code on Windows Phone 7. Basically you need to be writing .NET code - so any libraries you want to use have to be .NET libraries too. (And not just that, but compatible with Windows Phone 7, so Silverlight at an appropriate version.)

If you tell us which library you're using, we can try to help you find something similar.

Comment: I am using private jar , is name is molad: http://molad.palmcrust.com/ this is for Jewish shabbat